# Argument length of Zero - IF statment

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a table I've made to output into a pdf for distribution, however, I keep getting an argument length of zero as an error.

my df looks like this, but is 80 rows long:

```
       DM   MPH_Over Variance
1    ATLR  1.8277662 9.972406
2    BAKA  2.9154519 6.692614
3    SERF  9.1898734 6.633396
4    DKRE  0.9621212 6.723101
```

The code I've gotten is as follows.

```
library(gridExtra)
names(dmover) <- c("DM","MPH_Over","Variance")

dmovertab <- as.data.frame(dmover[1,])
EmptyLine <- data.frame(DM = "",MPH_Over = "",Variance = "")

pdf(file = "q.pdf")

for (i in 2:nrow(dmover)) 
{
  if ((nrow(dmover$MPH_Over[i]))  ==  (nrow(dmover$MPH_Over[i-1])))
  {dmovertab <- rbind(dmovertab, dmover[i,])}

  else {
    dmovertab <- rbind(dmovertab, EmptyLine)
    dmovertab <- rbind(dmovertab, dmover[i,]) 
  }
}

grid.table(dmovertab,rows=NULL)
dev.off()
```

It keeps throwing an error (below) while outputting a .pdf table of 1 row? I do feel like I'm doing something small wrong and I'm going to be an idiot when someone tells me what I've messed up. Any help you can give me to fix this if conditional would be great.

> Error in if ((nrow(dmover$MPH_Over[i])) == (nrow(dmover$MPH_Over[i - 1]))) { : 
>     argument is of length zero"

Comment: See the result of `nrow(1:10)` and `nrow(1:10) == nrow(1:10)` and `nrow(1:10)`. maybe you just want `dmover$MPH_Over[i]  ==  dmover$MPH_Over[i-1]`?

Comment: Doing that breaks the output to an inoperable PDF.  

But there aren't any errors.

Comment: I usually use `xtables` for ouputting latex tables. An easier method is to use knitr and the `kable` function. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365502/aligning-columns-with-knitr-kable-function/41365608#41365608) for a simple example using rmarkdown.

Comment: undefined columns means that you are asking R to subset non-existent columns. try removing the `[]` and whatever is inside of it, like `1:5`.

Comment: Sure.  I'll try your method.  Never done an .rmd before, so here's to hoping I get it right

Comment: These are nice. You can also put together memos/reports etc with this technology. Graphs, text, tables, a bit of formatting, latex math, and access to your variables all in one file.

Comment: It appears your method outputs a broken pdf, too?

Comment: It works for me. This sounds potentially like an OS issue with the PDF constructor. I'd search for this issue, on the internet. Maybe update all your software and trying it again?

Comment: I just reinstalled Rstudio and R today, actually.

Comment: and updated all the packages? If so, it's probably not the R software. I've heard of some issues with OSX, which I don't use.

Comment: I use Windows 10.

Comment: Just tinkered a bit and it's saying that object dmover doesn't exist.

Comment: You have to construct a codeblock that constructs this object. Easiest to just save it in you current session and then put a `load` statement in the Rmd file, but maybe better to use the code that constructs it in the codeblock.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that.  Got any resources I could look up on?

Comment: You could start with `?save` and `?load`. The parts of the Rmd file delimited by 3 backticks are called codeblocks. More on Rmarkdown [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) and basics [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_basics.html).

Comment: Thanks.  It tells me I need pandoc or Miktex but the install.packages states that its' not available for 3.3.2.  Is there a LaTeX engine for 3.3.2?

Comment: Aha. That must be it. MikTex is a standalone application that is used with Windows for processing Latex documents. Here is [their site](https://miktex.org/).