# How to center flushed-right column text in Kable?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable

I am having a dataframe with both character and numeric columns. I am trying to center the character column (which is done) and (I don't know how to) center flushed-right numeric column. Further, both column names are centered:
[image: desired look]

Some relevant posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143690/rmarkdown-kable-vertically-align-cells) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347799/how-to-center-a-block-of-the-lines-while-flushleft-flushright-is-applied)), but I couldn't incorporate the techniques (if relevant) to my code.

The following code produces the table below:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "bb", "ccc"), number = c(10, 193048, 200))

kable(df, format="latex", align = c("c", "r")) %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = TRUE) %>% 
  row_spec(0, align = "c")
```

[image: current look]

I understand that I can use LaTeX code to produce a single user-customised table. But I need the example to be reproducible in Rmd (imagine I have lots of `df`) and therefore need to specify within `kable()`.

Should I modify the LaTeX table environment (i.e. `\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {>{\centering}X>{\centering}X}`) and if so how in R, or use something like `multirow` to customise the second column??

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365502/aligning-columns-with-knitr-kable-function/41365608#41365608) might be relevant. It doesn't use Latex directly, though.

Comment: Thank you @Imo, I may have missed it, but I didn't see any info on center *and* right alignment for the column.

Comment: This combo does not appear to be possible directly in `kable`. You may be able to fake it using `sprintf` with the proper formatting, ie adding enough blank spaces to get it to look good enough. Take a look at the examples in the manual page if you want to give that a try. Alternatively, there are a number of alternative table functions, `xtable`, and something in `hmisc`, also the package `tables`. Good luck.

Comment: Will give these options a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Fran from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481821/how-to-center-and-flush-right-cells-in-a-column/481831?noredirect=1#comment1218779_481831), answer below:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "bb", "ccc"), number = c(10, 193048, 200))

kable(df,"latex", align="cr", booktabs = T, linesep = "") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "3em") %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "3em")
```